# How to call the original class's code when a class helper is in scope?

Tags: delphi, class-helpers

I'm doing some unit testing on an improved version of quicksort.
The (hopefully) faster version is implemented using:

```
TArrayHelper = class helper for System.Generics.Collections.TArray
....
   class procedure Sort<T>(var Values: array of T); overload; static;
   class procedure Sort<T>(var Values: array of T; Comparer: IComparer<T>); overload; static;
....
```

I know for now I can just rename the `Sort` into `SortNew` for the purpose of testing, but at some point I have to fix the method names to `sort`.

**If there is a class helper in scope, how do I call the original methods?**

Is there a way using rtti or some other roundabout method?

Comment: Class helper seems to *rule them all*. I don't see a point of using the same name for a method in a helper though. I'm taking helpers as a tool for extending, not for overriding.

Comment: Why do you not replace/implement the class procedure QuickSort directly in your helper?

Comment: @TLama, the point is to foist faster `sort` methods on people without them knowing. It's part of a government plot. That way the NSA can spy on you without them having to rewrite your code.

Comment: Fair enough :-) P.S. the only way I've been thinking of failed (typecast the instance with the fully qualified name), hence I said that it seems they rule them all.

Comment: @LURD, Excellent Idea, but -I just remembered- I cannot, because the IComparer in my unit is not the same IComparer as in System.Generics.Collections.  I'm bending the rules.

Comment: Speeding up the Quick Sort using generics? That I gotta see. If you manage to pull this off I might change my current thinking about Generics as being bad for performance.

Comment: @SilverWarior He's not claiming that generics can be used to speed up quicksort. He's talking about a more efficient implementation of `TArray.Sort<T>`. Generics generally has no performance implications. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @SilverWarior, generic code is **not** slower than normal code. However the implementation that Emba uses does cause code bloat, which can cause issues with the cache. In order to combat this clever tricks have to be used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is my existing experience so far with generics that are making me think about them in such way.

Comment: @SilverWarior I suspect you are drawing erroneous conclusions

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps. I assume you have probably done some performance testing of Generics yourself. Right? Well so far results of my tests were against the favor of Generics. But then again I might have used the generics in wrong way.

Comment: Generics code is identical to non generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way to achieve this with pure Pascal code is to call `Sort` from a scope in which your class helper is not active. The point being that if your class helper is active, then `Sort` refers to the method in the helper.

For instance like this:

```
unit ScopeBuster;

interface;

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TArrayScopeBuster = class
    class procedure Sort<T>(...); overload; inline; static;
  end;

implementation

class procedure TArrayScopeBuster.Sort<T>(...); 
begin
  TArray.Sort(...);
end;

end.
```

Comment: It wouldn't be very elegant, but there it is